# 504 Gateway Timeout error with NuxtJS application running on Nginx

Tags: node.js, nginx, nuxtjs

I have a Nuxt JS SSR site hosted on digital ocean. I am using nginx as reverse proxy with configuration as described at Nuxtjs [website](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/deployment/nginx-proxy). I also use pm2 to run nuxt app. Everything works fine until I gat 504 and 502 errors. When I check ngnix logs it shows erros like this:

> "[error] 2767773#2767773: *1655282 upstream timed out (110: Connection
> timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client:
> x.x.x.x, server: leadersport.ge, request: "GET /news/devils HTTP/1.1",
> upstream: "http://x.x.x.x:8000/xxxx/xxxx", host: "xxx.com"

It seems like there is problem with Nuxtjs app. I inspected my Nuxtjs application(I use pm2 monit, and also I log every error inside my nuxtjs app) but it seems to work fine. After 504 error I check nuxtjs logs and there seems to be no problem. Could it be that I miss something regarding nuxtjs app? If so how could I find out what is exactly the problem with nuxtjs app? Or could it be the problem with nginx configuration?

I also check memory and cpu usage and it seems to be okay.

Comment: were you able to resolve this issue? I'm currently faced with the same issue.

Comment: Hey, there was a problem with the NuxtJS application. It was sending more requests than Nginx could respond to. But the important thing for me was that I had WordPress API as a backend to which NuxtJS was sending requests. When I configured the NuxtJS application to send fewer API requests and increased server capacity at Digitalocean, there were no more 504 errors. However, if there is very high traffic, there are still 504 errors, in that case, you need to increase server capacity or optimize your application even more.